# What does "auf dem Zettel" mean in this sentence?

Tags: german-to-english

I was listening to a podcast and the host said:
"Wir haben so viele Themen **auf dem Zettel**"

I looked it up and *note* doesn't seem like a proper translation, can someone help me with the exact meaning of this?

Comment: This phrase is rather informal. I would not use it when talking to an "official" audience.

Answer (score 8):

A “Zettel” is a piece of paper. This usage is (probably) somewhat figuratively, they are just saying that they have a long list of topics.

Incidentally, [Zettel](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Zettel) is related to English [schedule](https://www.etymonline.com/word/schedule).

Comment: Correct, "etwas auf dem Zettel haben" means to have something on your (figurative) to-do list, agenda, run sheet etc. You can imagine having those written on an actual piece of paper. You can also use "ich habe es auf dem Zettel" similar to "I've got it on my list (of tasks), I'll take care of it".